# How to update files in AWS S3 maintaining high availability

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am storing my files in S3 which are being accessed from JAVA code placed in EC2.

These files need to be updated frequently.

So my question is, how to updated these files and maintain high availability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I understand is that you have some files which are modified day to day and then uploaded to S3.

1. You can keep doing that and uploading files to S3 from your java app and AWS automatically maintains high availability across multiple availability zones and you don't need to worry about data loss.
2. Assume you have a file abc.html which you have uploaded on S3. Next time you modify the file and upload on S3, AWS will overwrite/replace that  file and you will have the latest content in that file.
3. In case you want to maintain different versions of the same file, you can go ahead and use AWS S3 versioning. You can read more about that here:
   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html

Also, since you're using S3 you can use AWS S3 acceleration for faster file access into your application: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html

Comment: When I am updating file let say abc.html and same time there is a request to read the content. Will there be any lock or S3 will allow him to read and in background S3 will create new file and once file writing is complete the S3 will start pointing out latest file and further read request will access latest file.

Comment: Yes. The new version if you're uploading with same name, replaces the older file okay? but till the time the new file content is not replicated across all AZs it is not readable. So, read request will still go to older file and then subsequent requests will go to new file. Hope I answered your queries. @AnkurGupta

Comment: Great, looks satisfactory answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

S3 provides [read-after-write consistency for PUT operations of new objects](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel), and eventual consistency for overwrite PUTs and DELETEs. If you need read-after-write consistency for overwrites and deletions, you could store all objects in S3 as new items, keying them on their SHA256 of the content and mapping the SHA256 keys to the desired paths in DynamoDB. AWS EMRFS on S3 uses DynamoDB for metadata with their [Consistent View](http://docs.aws.amazon.com//emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-consistent-view.html) feature.